# Adding +1 every time radiobox is used

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to add +1 every time a radiobox or checkbox is used. This happens when calculate is pressed and putting it into a string then when the summary button is pushed it displays it in a messagebox with the final total of times it was pushed.

this is my code so far but it doesnt seem to work,
This is my Calculate button

```
        int Quantity; 
        int Finalprice;

        if (lunchRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
           Meal = Lunch;

        }
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked && waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Waiter + Table;


        }
        else if (waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Waiter;

        }
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Table;

        }

        //Early Evening Meal
        if (earlyEveningRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            Meal = Early;

        }

        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked && waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
           Extras = Table + Waiter;


        }
        else if (waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Waiter;

        }
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Table;

        }

        //Late evening options
        if (lateEveningRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            Meal = Late;

        }

        //Late Evening, Corner table and Dedicated waiter selected.
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked && waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Table + Waiter;

        }

        //Late Evening and Dedicated waiter selected.
        else if (waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
           Extras = Waiter;

        }

        //Late Evening and Corner Table
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Table;
            ;
        }

        try
        {
            Quantity = int.Parse(guestTextBox.Text);
            Mealprice = (Meal * Quantity);
            Finalprice = (Mealprice + Extras);
            finalAmountLabel.Text = Finalprice.ToString("C");

        }
        catch
        {
            guestTextBox.Focus();
            guestTextBox.SelectAll();
           MessageBox.Show("Please enter a quantity in numerical form","Quantity Error!");
        }
```

This is the Summary Button

```
        int TotalLunch = 0;
        int TotalEarly = 0;
        int TotalLate = 0;
        int TotalBookings = 0;

        int TotalWaiters = 0;
        int LateWaiters = 0;
        int EarlyWaiters = 0;
        int LunchWaiters = 0;

        int TotalCornerTables = 0;
        int EarlyCornerTables = 0;
        int LateCornerTables = 0;
        int LunchCornerTables = 0;

        if (earlyEveningRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            TotalEarly = +1;
            TotalEarly.ToString();
        }
        else if (earlyEveningRadioButton.Checked && waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            EarlyWaiters = +1;
            EarlyWaiters.ToString();
        }
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked && earlyEveningRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            EarlyCornerTables = +1;
            EarlyCornerTables.ToString();
        }
        else if (waiterCheckBox.Checked && tableCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            EarlyWaiters = +1;
                EarlyCornerTables = +1;
                EarlyWaiters.ToString();
                EarlyCornerTables.ToString();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Number of Early Bookings" + " " + TotalEarly + "   " + 
                        "Number of Early Evening Waiters" + " " + EarlyWaiters
                        + "number of Early Evening Corner Tables tables" + " " + EarlyCornerTables

                         );
```

Any suggestions or help would be greately appriciated :)

Comment: 1) It is not really obvious what you are trying to achieve. Do you really want to increment the values every time the `CheckBox` is checked? If so, you should rather use a `Button` instead of a `CheckBox`. 2) Are you sure that you are familiar with the most basic rules of programming? Like visibility of variables, operators...

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can do this, is using the eventhandler CheckedChanged foreach checkbox.

in the event do this:

```
if(checkBox.Checked)
{
    //int +1
}
```

Comment: I do not think that the OP really wants to increment the value every time the RadioButton is checked. At least, this would not make sense...

Comment: I quote: "I'm wanting to add +1 every time a radiobox or checkbox is used." Looks like he DOES want that :)

Comment: Yeah, I know he *wrote* that, but I cannot imagine he actually *meant* that. If he did, then everything is lost. :)

Comment: Agreed. But I'm giving my answer according to what his question is.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with an answer to your question...

Your code will not *increment* `TotalEarly` by one, but it will *assign* `+1` to the variable.

```
TotalEarly = +1;
```

For incrementing you should either use the `++` or the `+=` operator:

```
TotalEarly++; // increments by 1
TotalEarly += 1; // also increments by 1, but += can be used with other numbers
```

---

Some other notes, not related to your question:

```
TotalEarly.ToString();
```

This will not do anything since you do not assign the result to a variable. This will *not* convert `TotalEarly` to a string variable! The type of `TotalEarly` is fixed to `int` as you specified.

You would have to write

```
var totalEarlyString = TotalEarly.ToString();
```

to be able to use the result afterwards. You might wonder why your MessageBox still displays that number as a string although you use the `int` variable:

```
"Number of Early Bookings" + " " + TotalEarly
```

This is because the `ToString()` method is called automatically in this case. So, you can really save some lines by removing your calls to `ToString()` after the assignments.

---

One more thing: local variables are typically named using `camelCase`. That means, the first character is lower case and every additional word starts with an uppercase character. `PascalCase` (i.e. also starting with uppercase character) is typically used for properties, methods, class names etc, but not for local or member variables.

---

It seems like you want each value in the MessageBox to be on a separate line (at least I assume that is why you added some spaces at the end of the first line:

```
MessageBox.Show("Number of Early Bookings" + " " + TotalEarly + "   " + 
                    "Number of Early Evening Waiters" + " " + EarlyWaiters
                    + "number of Early Evening Corner Tables tables" + " " + EarlyCornerTables
                     );
```

This might not work on all machines. The MessageBox has different sizing behavior on differnt versions of Windows. Some will wrap the text to multiple lines, some will not, or at least at different widths!

Therefore, you better add an `Environment.NewLine` at the end of each line. This will add a line break to your string which will be interpreted as such by the MessageBox:

```
MessageBox.Show("Number of Early Bookings " + TotalEarly + Environment.NewLine +
                "Number of Early Evening Waiters " + EarlyWaiters + Environment.NewLine +
                "Number of Early Evening Corner Tables tables " + EarlyCornerTables);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordion to your comments in your code I think the problem is that your if else statements are wrong.

Q1: Should it calculate on every checkbox click or only when you click calculate?
- if it should calculate on every checkbox click then you have to use the CheckedChanged event as RaZor points out.

Q2: Is it true that de client can have a lunch + waiter + table?
- if that is true then your if else statement should be as follows:

```
if (lunchRadioButton.Checked == true)
{
    Meal = Lunch;

    if (tableCheckBox.Checked && waiterCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        Extras = Waiter + Table;
    }
    else if (waiterCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        Extras = Waiter;

    }
    else if (tableCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        Extras = Table;

    }
}
```